# Simulate MySQL connection to analyze queries to rebuild table structure (reverse-engineering tables)

Tags: php, mysql, reverse-engineering

I have just been tasked with recovering/rebuilding an extremely large and complex website that had no backups and was fully lost.  I have a complete (hopefully) copy of all the PHP files however I have absolutely no clue what the database structure looked like (other than it is certainly at least 50 or so tables...so fairly complex).  All data has been lost and the original developer was fired about a year ago in a fiery feud (so I am told).  I have been a PHP developer for quite a while and am plenty comfortable trying to sort through everything and get the application/site back up and running...but the lack of a database will be a huge struggle.  So...is there any way to simulate a MySQL connection to some software that will capture all incoming queries and attempt to use the requested field and table names to rebuild the structure?

It seems to me that if i start clicking through the application and it passes a query for

> SELECT `name`, `email`, `phone` from `contact_table` WHERE
>   `contact_id`='1'

...there should be a way to capture that info and assume there was a table called "contact_table" that had at least 4 fields with those names...  If I can do that repetitively, each time adding some sample data to the discovered fields and then moving on to another page, then eventually I should have a rough copy of most of the database structure (at least all public-facing parts).  This would be MUCH easier than manually reading all the code and pulling out every reference, reading all the joins and subqueries, and sorting through it all manually.

Anyone ever tried this before?  Any other ideas for reverse-engineering the database structure from PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log=1;
```

With this configuration enabled, the MySQL server writes every query to a log file (`datadir/hostname.log` by default), even those queries that have errors because the tables and columns don't exist yet.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html says:

> The general query log can be very useful when you suspect an error in a client and want to know exactly what the client sent to mysqld.

As you click around in the application, it should generate SQL queries, and you can have a terminal window open running `tail -f` on the general query log.  As you see queries run by that reference tables or columns that don't exist yet, create those tables and columns.  Then repeat clicking around in the app.

A number of things may make this task even harder:

- If the queries use `SELECT *`, you can't infer the names of columns or even how many columns there are.  You'll have to inspect the application code to see what column names are used after the query result is returned.
- If INSERT statements omit the list of column names, you can't know what columns there are or how many.  On the other hand, if INSERT statements *do* specify a list of column names, you can't know if there are more columns that were intended to take on their default values.
- Data types of columns won't be apparent from their names, nor string lengths, nor character sets, nor default values.
- Constraints, indexes, primary keys, foreign keys won't be apparent from the queries.
- Some tables may exist (for example, lookup tables), even though they are never mentioned by name by the queries you find in the app.
- Speaking of lookup tables, many databases have sets of initial values stored in tables, such as all possible user types and so on.  Without the knowledge of the data for such lookup tables, it'll be hard or impossible to get the app working.
- There may have been triggers and stored procedures.  Procedures may be referenced by `CALL` statements in the app, but you can't guess what the code inside triggers or stored procedures was intended to be.

This project is bound to be very laborious, time-consuming, and involve a lot of guesswork.  The fact that the employer had a big feud with the developer might be a warning flag.  Be careful to set the expectations so the employer understands it will take a lot of work to do this.

PS: I'm assuming you are using a recent version of MySQL, such as 5.1 or later.  If you use MySQL 5.0 or earlier, you should just add `log=1` to your /etc/my.cnf and restart mysqld.

Comment: Thanks Bill!  This is the best solution thus far, but I will leave it open a bit longer in case something else comes along.  Yes, I agree that it will still be a tedious process that will involve a lot of guessing at types, constraints, etc...but I am hopeful that if I can at least get a basic structure together for the data, then I can hopefully figure out the rest of everything from code analysis wherever an error is thrown.  This project will certainly be a royal pain (perhaps even impossible)...but at least it should be an interesting challenge!  Wouldn't want to get bored :-)

Answer (score 0):

Crazy task.  Is the code such that the DB queries are at all abstracted?  Could you replace the query functions with something which would log the tables, columns and keys, and/or actually create the tables or alter them as needed, before firing off the real query?

Alternatively, it might be easier to do some text processing, regex matching, grep/sort/uniq on the queries in all of the PHP files.  The goal would be to get it down to a manageable list of all tables and columns in those tables.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar task, fortunately I was able to find an old backup.

If you could find a way to extract the queries, like say, regex match all of the occurrences of `mysql_query` or whatever extension was used to query the database, you could then use something like [php-sql-parser](http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/) to parse the queries and hopefully from that you would be able to get a list of most tables and columns. However, that is only half the battle. The other half is determining the data types for every single column and that would be rather impossible to do autmatically from PHP. It would basically require you inspect it line by line. There are best practices, but who's to say that the old dev followed them? Determining whether a column called "date" should be stored in `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `INT`, or `VARCHAR(50)` with some sort of manual ugly string thing can only be determined by looking at the actual code.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could build some triggers with the BEFORE action time, but unfortunately this will only work for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE commands.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html